# Using cURL to add items to Shopify cart

Tags: php, post, curl, shopify

I am attempting to **remotely** add an item to a Shopify cart using the Shopify API. I am doing this in PHP with cURL as follows:

```
$link   = $api_url . '/cart/add.js'; // http://usr:pass@the-shop.myshopify.com/cart/add.js
$vars   = 'id=10672241284';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

However this is not actually posting anything. I have also tried (with no vars):

```
$link   = $api_url . '/cart/add/10672241284';
```

But nothing happens. I have errors turned on but nothing returns. I use `echo $link;` and then paste that link into the address bar and it works fine, so it isn't the link that's being generated... Am I using cURL or the Shopify API wrong?

**UPDATE:** As suggested by @Matt:

```
echo "Curl Error No:" . curl_errno($ch); // returns "0"
echo "Curl HTTP Code:" . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // returns "400"
```

Comment: Could you please try `echo "Curl Error No:" . curl_errno($ch);` and `echo "Curl HTTP Code:" . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` after your curl execution?

Comment: @Matt `Curl Error No:0` and `Curl HTTP Code:400` respectively. 400 means it's not finding the file?

Comment: 400 generally means "Bad Request" e.g. The data you're sending to the URL is not sufficient or invalid. Just took a look at the API and it also has `quantity` as a required post field as well as the ID. Try adding quantity in there and tell me how it goes.

Comment: @Matt ok now I get a `Curl HTTP Code: 200` but it's still not adding anything to the cart.

Comment: The only suggestion I would have is to make sure that the ID is right and that the quantity is right. I'm not too sure further than that with the shopify API as the request is going through successfully.

Comment: Yea, both are correct. As I said in the post: when I copy and paste the generated link (http://usr:pass@the-shop.myshopify.com/cart/add.js?id=1067224128`) into my address bar it works fine and adds it to cart. I'll seek support directly from Shopify if possible since it seems as if cURL is being implemented correctly. Thanks for your time @matt

Comment: I tried and work, but the item only is added in the curl environment, what do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are barking up the wrong tree. Try using Javascript. The right tool for the job. Executing PHP to add something to cart? Can you explain the need for that? Makes no sense as no browser executes PHP client-side, but all execute JS client-side, which is what you need here. Why are you trying server-side code to add something to a cart?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion, I mentioned but didn't stress: this is coming from a remote server, not the same server that Shopify is hosted on - otherwise you wouldn't be able to do anything like this in the first place if this was happening in Shopify. Server-side scripting necessary.

Comment: If you read the articles and docs on remotely adding items to a cart, you'll see it has nothing to do with cURL either. In almost all cases, using cURL is for making a GET/POST/PUT or DELETE on a resource using the authenticated API calls of Shopify. Not for adding items to a cart.

Comment: But in that case, why wouldn't you be able to POST to the `/cart/add` in an authenticated call to Shopify via cURL? I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to use shopify admin api (REST APIS) in php not the cart js method as it is only used in javascript front end not server end. Or if you want customize at cart at front end you need to use shopify scripts
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/shopify-scripts